# React.setState doesn't update as expected in useHook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React hook:

```
const useWidgets = () => {
    const [skip, setSkip] = useState(0);
    const take = 20;

    async function getItems() {
        try {
            console.log('skip is always 0 here', skip);

            const rsp = await apiGetWidgets({ skip });
            setSkip((state) => state + take);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getItems();
    }, []);

    return {  getItems, skip };
};
```

And I have a functionalComponent, that consumes the hook:

```
const Infinite: FC = () => {
    const { getItems, skip } = useWidgets();

    
    useEffect(()=> {
        setTimeout(getItems, 4000)
    }, [])
    
    console.log('skip is updated here to latest value', skip);

    return <div>
        {skip}
    </div>
};
```

When `skip` is updated by `setSkip` the value change is updated in the functional Component but that change is not reflected in the `useWidget` hook, `skip` is always zero.

Is this because the useWidgets hook closed over the initial value of `skip` which starts out at zero?

I thought any subsequent calls to `getItems` would be able to access the new value of `skip` but it remains at zero. Every time the functional component `Infinite` gets re-rendered I thought a new call to `useWidgets` would be called and the latest value of `skip` would be maintained, but I guess it reinitializes at zero?

Can anyone explain the behavior of why I cant access current state in the `useWidgets` hook, but the functionalComponent `Infinite` can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the closure is not happening inside the `useWidgets` but it is happening inside the `useEffect` of the `Infinite` component.

The `getItems` in that `useEffect` is the one from the initial render of the component, so it uses the *"first"* defined `getItems`. It just delays its execution due to the timeout.

If you add a button inside the `Infinite` component that invokes the `getItems` you will see that it is getting the correct one.

See demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/af-react-sandbox-d5spdh?file=index.js

Comment: Interesting. Not sure I quite follow yet what is happening in your example. However, I have provided a complete link to my test case where you can see that the `getItems` api does not have access to the current state of `skip`.

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/af-react-sandbox-iyxeqh?file=index.js

Comment: @user3146945 it is the same thing. The `useEffect` inside the `InterSectionObserverLoader` uses the `callback` (the `getItems`). But that `useEffect` is never triggered again (correctly) so inside it it has access to the `getItems` that it was provided at the time it was run. If you want a fresh `getItems` for your observer you will have to use a `ref` for it, or remove/readd the observer in each re-render (***not** what you want most likely*)

Comment: @user3146945 here is your demo with an update, using an extra `useRef`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/af-react-sandbox-auca2x?file=index.js,index.html

Comment: @Gabrielle Ok, that took me by surprise. Would you mind illustrating how to use a `ref` in that situation. Is the `IntersectionObserverLoader` component inherently flawed?

Comment: @user3146945 and another demo using the `unobserve`/`observe` on each re-render. https://stackblitz.com/edit/af-react-sandbox-ghunwu?file=index.js,index.html (*notice the dependency array*)

Comment: It is just that you are using a stale reference to the `getItems`. Each time your `useWidgets` is called it is returning a new `getItems` function. It is not updating the contents of the existing one. Your `InterSectionObserverLoader` is in effect caching the first one it receives and uses it for the `IntersectionObserver`.

Comment: @Gabrielle Thanks for the updated example, I have some work to do to understand the mechanics. One note though, in the react docs it says: "You shouldn’t read (or write) the current value during rendering." Is what you did considered a band-aid to fix a flawed component?